# I cannot read several columns in room database

Tags: android, android-room

I'm trying read id and first name using room database but I got this error before run app :

> Schema export directory is not provided to the annotation processor so
>   we cannot export the schema. You can either provide
>   `room.schemaLocation` annotation processor argument OR set
>   exportSchema to false.

There is no problem if I read id or first name separately but I can't read id and first name together

*Code Example (This is working without any problem)*

```
AppDatabase appDatabase;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_categories);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        appDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(CategoriesActivity.this, AppDatabase.class, "RDatabase").allowMainThreadQueries().build();
        Log.w("name", appDatabase.userDao().getAll());
    }

    @Entity
    public class User {
        @PrimaryKey
        int uid;

        @ColumnInfo(name = "first_name")
        String firstName;
    }

    @Dao
    public interface UserDao {
        @Insert
        void insertAll(User... users);

        @Query("SELECT first_name FROM user")
        String getAll();
    }

    @Database(entities = {User.class}, version = 1)
    public abstract static class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
        public abstract UserDao userDao();
    }
```

*Code Example (This is not working because I read id and first name together)*

```
AppDatabase appDatabase;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_categories);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        appDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(CategoriesActivity.this, AppDatabase.class, "RDatabase").allowMainThreadQueries().build();
        List<User> a = appDatabase.userDao().getAll();
        Log.w("aaa","" + a.get(0).uid);
    }

    @Entity
    public class User {
        @PrimaryKey
        int uid;

        @ColumnInfo(name = "first_name")
        String firstName;
    }

    @Dao
    public interface UserDao {
        @Insert
        void insertAll(User... users);

        @Query("SELECT uid,first_name FROM user")
        List<User> getAll();
    }

    @Database(entities = {User.class}, version = 1)
    public abstract static class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
        public abstract UserDao userDao();
    }
```

I tried put `exportSchema to false` after version but I got this error

> error: an enclosing instance that contains CategoriesActivity.User is
>   required

Comment: because your getAll method is expecting return type of User object.

Comment: @Gautam Ok what can I do for solve it , Could you leave example ?

Comment: I don't know what exactly you want from your DB but you can just use this query- SELECT * FROM user

Comment: @Gautam I did that hours ago but same.

Comment: @Gautam I found solution , You can move inner classes to independent classes only.